# neuropy problem having module not callable type error

Tags: python

I wrote this simple program after my installation in my anaconda3 jupyter:

```
from NeuroPy import NeuroPy
from time import sleep

neuropy = NeuroPy() 
neuropy.start()

while True:
    if neuropy.meditation > 70: # Access data through object
        neuropy.stop() 
    sleep(0.2) # Don't eat the CPU cycles
```

But its giving this type error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         2 from time import sleep
>         3 
>   ----> 4 neuropy = NeuroPy()
>         5 neuropy.start()
>         6
>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

This is because both the function and class is named NeuroPy. I face similar problem with this.
Try neuropy = NeuroPy.NeuroPy()